# SQL Server SUM based on another column IF start & stop times don't overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2008 and I'm trying to create a column to Sum `Duration` over `Nominal_Date`, `ID`, and `CODE` `IF AUD_ACTN = ADD` AND there *isn't* an `AUD_ACTN = UPDATE` which overlaps the original `ADD` (see Start_Time & Stop_Time). If there is an `UPDATE` which overlaps, then I want to sum the Duration of the `UPDATE` row and ignore the original `ADD` row. In my data there will always be either 1 'ADD', or 1 'ADD' + any number of 'UPDATE' rows (generally just one 'UPDATE' though), in a scenario where multiple 'UPDATE' rows exist, the most recent 'Upd_Timestamp' should take precedence.

Maybe there's a smarter way to go about this but basically the intent is that if a row is `ADD`ed, but then `UPDATE`ed to a different duration I want to capture the duration of the most recent update.

Here's a small sample of my data

```
ID  CODE    Nominal_Date    Start_Time  Stop_Time   Duration_Mins   AUD_ACTN    Upd_Timestamp
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 20:30   360 ADD 11/1/16 2:25
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 11:00   330 UPDATE  11/9/16 11:33
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 8:00    150 UPDATE  3/2/17 18:41
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 12:30   180 ADD 3/10/17 5:43
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 17:30   180 UPDATE  3/10/17 5:43
1   -989999998371.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 10:00   30  UPDATE  11/9/16 11:33
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 20:30   360 ADD 11/1/16 2:25
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 11:00   330 ADD 11/9/16 11:33
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 8:00    150 UPDATE  3/2/17 18:41
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 12:30   180 ADD 3/10/17 5:43
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 17:30   180 UPDATE  3/10/17 5:43
1   -989999970399.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 10:10   3/10/17 10:25   15  ADD 3/10/17 10:10
1   -989999970399.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 10:17   3/10/17 10:25   8   UPDATE  3/10/17 21:18
1   -989858416947.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:15    3/10/17 10:30   75  ADD 11/9/16 11:33
```

The output should look something like this

```
ID  CODE    Nominal_Date    Start_Time  Stop_Time   Duration_Mins
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 8:00    150
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 12:30   180
1   -989999998387.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 17:30   180
1   -989999998371.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 10:00   30
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 5:30    3/10/17 8:00    150
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:30    3/10/17 12:30   180
1   -989999970415.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 14:30   3/10/17 17:30   180
1   -989999970399.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 10:17   3/10/17 10:25   8
1   -989858416947.0 3/10/2017   3/10/17 9:15    3/10/17 10:30   75
```

Hopefully this makes sense, let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Show some sample output even one row of your sample data.

Comment: if there is just 1 second overlap, the update has the priority?

Comment: regarding cardinality, you have either 1 add or 1 add and 1 update? or you can have several update for 1 add? or 1 update overlapping several add?

Comment: i think the OP don't have a right to reply the comment coz he has only 1 reputation.

Comment: then maybe OP can edit his own question and add some explanations according to our comments. And flag them as EDIT so we can notice it.

Comment: I just added a sample output for the data. In regards to cardinality there should always be 1 ADD, or 1 ADD + any number of UPDATE (generally just one UPDATE though), the most recent timestamp on UPDATE should take precedence. I updated my sample data as well since the original data I provided was missing some of the original ADDs.

Comment: To answer your other question, yes if there is even 1 second overlap, the update would have priority.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if this is what you want:

Sample Data that over lap in 12 hours:

```
select rowNumber, id,code,nominal_date,start_time,stop_time,duration_mins,upd_timestamp,HourDiff,case when HourDiff>12 then 'yes' else 'no' end as Overlap  from
(select row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as rowNumber, id,code,nominal_date,start_time,stop_time,duration_mins,upd_timestamp,floor(datediff(Hour,start_time,stop_time))as HourDiff from @tb) as a
```

I just include the `rownumber` hoping that perhaps you need it.

This one get the count of Over Lap  in 12 hours:

```
select count(1) from @tb where  floor(datediff(Hour,start_time,stop_time)) > 12
```

You can change it to Over Lap in `24hrs`.

Maybe this answer served as your guide to get the `Sum`.. Coz it's not too clear to me.